# Jquery: How can I compute total average of each function based from the values in the input type = number?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am new to Javascript/Jquery and I would like to compute the final rating based from the value in the text box for each function name [1st column of the table] (core function, support function, research services).

[image]

The formula based from example:

1. Final Rating Core Administrative Function = (4.6 + 4.3)/2 (because there are only 2 core functions average value is available) * 0.65
2. Final Rating Support Function = (4.3 + 4.3)/2 * 0.2275
3. Final Rating for Research Function = (4 + 4)/2 * 0.1225

The requirement is that everytime the A value column of each row changes the final rating change as well.

Here is the Jquery of on how I get the A value:

```
//GET THE AVERAGE PER ROW
$(".q-value, .e-value, .t-value").change(function(){
    let currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    let EValue = parseInt(currentRow.find('.e-value').val());
    let QValue = parseInt(currentRow.find('.q-value').val());
    let TValue = parseInt(currentRow.find('.t-value').val());
    currentRow.find('.a-value').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / 3);
});
```

the .q-value, .e-value, .t-value, .a-value are all inside a class.

I add 3 input type for each final rating functions

```
<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="core-total" name="total_core" readonly>
<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="support-total" name="total_support" readonly>
<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="research-total" name="total_research" readonly>
```

so the value for each function will be dump in there.
Please help me on this. Im stuck in a days.

Comment: where is the function to update the data from A value to final result ?

Comment: You need to distinquish by class or otherwise what the rows are, core or support or research etc... so add those rows a class so you can select them. Then you can get all the rows with class with jquery selector and add the elements and divide by count. You insert that value to `$('#core-total').val(here*0.65);`
So the selector for the rows would be 

`let average = 0;  
$('tr.core-function .a-value').each(function(index){average += $(this).val()});  
average = average/$('tr.core-function .a-value').length;  
$('#core-total').val(average*0.65);`
You do that for each of those sub-totals

Comment: what I would do is group them by name, it will heavily depend on how you render that in your markup. if the markup is properly laid out, making computations will be easier, the opposite is the same, if the markup is jumbled, you'd have a lot of complicated jquery to employ just to group those values

Comment: I guess since he tagged laravel he uses template and that table is rendered with blade template engine so the task to add the classes for those rows would be trivial and sensible in design point of view. If it's a database table column value you can use that with some formatting as the class name and generate the jquery selectors dynamically in the blade template.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of my colleague, this is already resolved. I actually hardcoded an if statement in each input type for each functions (core, support etc..)

```
@if($row->function_name == 'Core Functions')
                                <input type="number" onchange="setFourNumberDecimal(this)" class="form-control form-control-sm a-value-core" name="A[]" style="width: 50px" readonly>
                            @elseif($row->function_name == 'Support Functions')
                                <input type="number" onchange="setFourNumberDecimal(this)" class="form-control form-control-sm a-value-support" name="A[]" style="width: 50px" readonly>
                            @endif
                            @if($row->function_name == 'Research and Extension Services')
                                <input type="number" onchange="setFourNumberDecimal(this)" class="form-control form-control-sm a-value-research" name="A[]" style="width: 50px" readonly>
                            @endif
```

After that. He created a JS function for computation.

```
//COMPUTE AVERAGE FOR EACH FUNCTION
    function computeAvg() {
        // For Core Functions
        const corevalues = document.getElementsByClassName("a-value-core")
        let avg = 0
        let total = 0
        let count = 0
        for (let x = 0; x < corevalues.length; x++) {
            if (corevalues[x].value !== "") {
                count++
                total = total + parseFloat(corevalues[x].value)
            }
        }
        avg = (total / count) * 0.65
        $('#core-total-average').val(isNaN(avg) ? "" : avg)

        // For Support Functons
        avg = 0
        total = 0
        count = 0
        const supvalues = document.getElementsByClassName("a-value-support")
        for (let x = 0; x < supvalues.length; x++) {
            if (supvalues[x].value !== "") {
                count++
                total = total + parseFloat(supvalues[x].value)
            }
        }
        avg = total / count * 0.2275
        $('#support-total-average').val(isNaN(avg) ? "" : avg)

        // For Research Services
        avg = 0
        total = 0
        count = 0
        const resvalues = document.getElementsByClassName("a-value-research")
        for (let x = 0; x < resvalues.length; x++) {
            if (resvalues[x].value !== "") {
                count++
                total = total + parseFloat(resvalues[x].value)
            }
        }
        avg = total / count * 0.1225
        $('#research-total-average').val(isNaN(avg) ? "" : avg)
    }
```